# How to set ingress.hosts[0].host in Helm chart via --set command line argument

Tags: command-line-arguments, kubernetes-helm

In a Helm chart, when trying to set the "ingress.hosts[0].host" via the --set command line argument, the "paths" array values specified in the values.yaml file do not get added to the final output.

I want to override the "ingress.hosts[0].host" key for deployment to different DNS zones on the command line. If I add the host to the values.yaml file, it does generate the correct ingress, but this would mean having different values.yaml files instead of re-using the same one, but with a different DNS zone.

**ingress.yaml Helm template**

```
rules:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
          {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ .path }}
            {{- if and .pathType (semverCompare ">=1.18-0" $.Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion) }}
            pathType: {{ .pathType }}
            {{- end }}
            backend:
              {{- if semverCompare ">=1.19-0" $.Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion }}
              service:
                name: {{ $fullName }}
                port:
                  number: {{ $svcPort }}
              {{- else }}
              serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
              servicePort: {{ $svcPort }}
              {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
```

**values.yaml** (Notice the single "path" object that should get added to the deployment.yaml file).

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  className: ""
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: addon-http-application-routing
  hosts:
  - host: 
    paths:
    - path: "/"
      pathType: Prefix
```

**command line**

```
helm template ./deploy/vehicleregistrationservice --set ingress.hosts[0].host=vehicleregistrationservice.aksapp.io --debug
```

**Invalid deployment file** (notice how the "paths" array is empty)

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: vehicleregistrationservice
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: vehicleregistrationservice-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: vehicleregistrationservice
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: addon-http-application-routing
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "vehicleregistrationservice.aksapp.io"
      http:
        paths:
```

**The deployment file is supposed to look like:**

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: vehicleregistrationservice
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: addon-http-application-routing
spec:
  rules:
  - host: vehicleregistrationservice.aksapp.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: 
            name: vehicleregistrationservice
            port: 
              number: 80
```

Comment: Related: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/11734

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just had the same problem.

Try something like `--set "ingress.hosts[0].host=yourhost.com,ingress.hosts[0].paths[0].path=/"`